# Ansible - specify host variables for a host used in multiple groups

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

Is there a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way to specify host variables for [hosts in multiple groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-in-multiple-groups)? e.g.:

```
all:
  hosts:
    mail.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.33
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.17
        bar.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.18
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.1
        two.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.2
        three.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.3
    test:
      hosts:
        bar.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.18 # Don't like this being defined in a 2nd place
        three.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.3  # =( Same
```

Is it possible to have host variables, like `ansible_host` in the example (or a SW license) defined in only one place? I wasn't able to find anything suitable in the ansible documentation, so the placeholder solution is to use [YAML anchors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#example-node-anchors):

```
all:
  hosts:
    mail.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.33
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.17
        bar.example.com: &bar
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.18
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.1
        two.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.2
        three.example.com: &three
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.3
    test:
      hosts:
        bar.example.com:
          << : *bar
        three.example.com:
          << : *three
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to have host variables, like ansible_host in the example (or a SW license) defined in only one place?

If you define variables for a host *anywhere* in your inventory file, those variables will be set for that host when Ansible runs. So for example, you could write your inventory like this:

```
all:
  hosts:
    mail.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.33
    foo.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.17
    bar.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.18
    one.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.1
    two.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.2
    three.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.3
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
        bar.example.com:
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
        two.example.com:
        three.example.com:
    test:
      hosts:
        bar.example.com:
        three.example.com:
```

But this would also work:

```
all:
  hosts:
    mail.example.com:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.33
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.17
        bar.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.18
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.1
        two.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.2
        three.example.com:
          ansible_host: 10.10.10.3
    test:
      hosts:
        bar.example.com:
        three.example.com:
```

I would argue that the first version is a bit more obvious.